# Can't geting proper percentage (%) result with javascript

Tags: javascript

I've simple javascript tools where a sum of percentage result is showing. But I can't get correct value. For example :

It's showing...

1000 % 10 = 100 It's right.
But 1000 % 10.2 = It's still showing 100. It's should be 102.

**Javascript code:**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('#pvalue1').change(function () {
        var agentfee = parseInt($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * parseInt($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) / 100;
        $('#pvalue3').val(agentfee);
        var percentagereduce = parseInt($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) - 0.1;
        var newvalue = parseInt($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * percentagereduce / 100;
        $('#pvalue4').val(newvalue);
        var takevalue1 = parseInt($('#pvalue3').val(), 10);
        var takevalue2 = parseInt($('#pvalue4').val(), 10);
        var finalvalue = takevalue1 - takevalue2;
        $('#pvalue5').val(finalvalue);
    });
    $('#pvalue2').change(function () {
        var agentfee = parseInt($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * parseInt($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) / 100;
        $('#pvalue3').val(agentfee);
        var percentagereduce = parseInt($('#pvalue2').val(), 10) - 0.1;
        var newvalue = parseInt($('#pvalue1').val(), 10) * percentagereduce / 100;
        $('#pvalue4').val(newvalue);
        var takevalue1 = parseInt($('#pvalue3').val(), 10);
        var takevalue2 = parseInt($('#pvalue4').val(), 10);
        var finalvalue = takevalue1 - takevalue2;
        $('#pvalue5').val(finalvalue);
    });
});
</script>
```

**Html part:**

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>House Sale Price:</td>
        <td>$
            <input name="pvalue1" onkeypress="validate(event)" value="" placeholder=" Enter Sale Price" style="width:140px;" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue1?>" id="pvalue1" size="20" class="required inputfield2" required>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rate quoted by agent:</td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input name="pvalue2" onkeypress="validate(event)" value="0" placeholder=" Percentage" style="width:140px;" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue2?>" id="pvalue2" size="20" class="required inputfield2" required>%</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input name="doRegister" type="submit" id="doRegister" value="Calculate" style="color:white;font-size:20px;" class="submitbutton">
<div id="resultbox2" class="resultbox1">
    <h2>Results</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Agent Fees:</td>
            <td>$
                <input name="pvalue3" value="0" placeholder="" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue3?>" id="pvalue3" size="10" class="resultfield">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id='show-me' style='display:none'>
                    <input name="pvalue4" value="0" placeholder="" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue4?>" id="pvalue4" size="10" class="resultfield">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Reducing the rate the agent is charging by 0.1% will save you:</td>
            <td>$
                <input name="pvalue5" value="0" placeholder="" type="number" value="<?=$pvalue5?>" id="pvalue5" size="10" class="resultfield">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Why are you using `parseInt` if you expect non-integers?

Comment: You have to use parseFloat instead of parseInt in an everywhere.

Comment: Some comments would help in understanding what the code is supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`parseInt` is only for integers, you need to use `parseFloat` if you are expecting integers and floats.

Comment: No problems, glad to help

Comment: You want to change the number? Or are you talking about rounding?

Comment: Use `toFixed()` `10.2356.toFixed(3) === 10.236`

Comment: I am, I can't help it really :P

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt` is throwing away the fractional part of your numbers, since the `.` and anything after it doesn't look like part of an integer. Try `parseFloat` instead.